# Use React createPortal to use same child component inside portal and parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to reuse the child component in both the parent and portal component. Portal component is a modal and parent holds a state that opens/closes the modal portal.The problem is, once the button clicks to open the portal then child component gets updated but not it the modal portal but in the parent component.

**Parent Component**

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ name: 'admin', openModal: false });
  

  const openPortal = () => {
   
    setState({
      name: 'user',
      openModal: true,
    });
  };

  if (state?.openModal) {
    return (
      <>
        <ModalPortal childComponent={<ReusableComp name={state.name} />} />
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ReusableComp name={state.name} />
      <button onClick={openPortal}>Open modal</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child Component - Reusable one**

```
const ReusableComp = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

**ModalPortal**

```
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

class ModalPortal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        {createPortal(this.props.childComponent, this.el)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalPortal;
```

[workingcode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3zmqy1?file=src%2FModalPortal.js) Any solution on this really helpful. The idea behind this approach is render that reusable child component in the modal too so that modal and modal behind DOM also would have the same component but different state based content.

**output1 - without modal portal view**

[image]

output2 - with modal portal view

[image]